Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', no carga correctamente los archivos .js
estoy intentando corregir un programa en C# .NET MVC, y al momento de compilarlo y comenzar a usarlo, en un botón que estoy usando javascript me da el siguiente error:

y checando en dónde se llama producto.js creo yo que esta correcto
´
<script src="~/Scripts/Categoria/Cargo.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/producto.js"></script> 

y producto.js está de esta forma:
function OpenAddModal(id) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/BuscaProducto/' + id,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf=8',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#modal-add-content').html(result);
                $('#modal-add').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (er) {
                alert(er);
            }
        });
}

este es el código del botón que debería de funcionar correctamente
<div style="text-align:right; padding:10px">
    <adata-modal ="" id="btnCreate" onclick="OpenAddModal(@ViewBag.IdVenta)" class="btn btn-success">    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/751/751381.png" width="20" height="20" alt="">  Producto</a>
</div>

si me pudieran ayudar a entender por qué se da este error y cómo podría solucionarlo, por favor

Hola. Esto contentType:'application/json; charset=utf=8' no corresponde con el tipo de contenido que estás mandando, pues mandas el dato en la URL: '/Home/BuscaProducto/' + id, ese tipo de contenido es contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', pero lo puedes omitir, pues ese es el contetType por defecto, según explica la doc: Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". Quítale ese parámetro y prueba de nuevo.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

@A.Cedano Buena observación, pero la causa de los errores está en otro lado.

@CarlosMuñoz de acuerdo. Hice las observaciones pertinentes en cuanto al código de la petición Ajax. No programo en C#, por eso no puede detectar fallos en ese aspecto. Espero que con tu respuesta se pueda resolver. Saludos.

Tienes 3 errores según esa consola:
Los dos primeros se deben a como defines las URLs
<script src="~/Scripts/Categoria/Cargo.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/producto.js"></script>

El carácter ~ no define una URL relativa si eso es lo que estás pensando.
Ese carácter sirve en una vista MVC (No en HTML) para ser reemplazada por los helpers del URL por una ruta relativa a la raiz del proyecto.
Lo que te hace falta es generar esta ruta y lo puedes lograr mediante. @Url.Content()
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Categoria/Cargo.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/producto.js")"></script>

Sin esto la ruta ~/Scripts/... no existe y por lo tanto los scripts fallan al cargar. El servidor arroja un error HTTP 404 y devuelve como contenido una página HTML, que empieza por el caracter < que no es javascript válido.
EL tercer error se debe a que como no se cargó producto.js la función OpenAddModal nunca fue definida y por lo tanto falla al llamarlo.
